# Remove rows in dataframe with factor ""

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like x where the column genes is a factor. I want to remove all the rows where column genes has nothing. So in table X I want to remove row 4. Is there a way to do this for a large dataframe?

```
X 
names   values   genes
1 A  0.2876113  EEF1A1 
2 B  0.6681894   GAPDH
3 C  0.1375420 SLC35E2
4 D -1.9063386        
5 E -0.4949905   RPS28
```

Finally result:

```
X 
names   values   genes
1 A  0.2876113  EEF1A1 
2 B  0.6681894   GAPDH
3 C  0.1375420 SLC35E2
5 E -0.4949905   RPS28
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not completely obvious from your question what the empty values are, but you should be able to adopt the solution below (here I assume the 'empty' values are empty strings):

```
toBeRemoved<-which(X$genes=="")
X<-X[-toBeRemoved,]
```

Comment: I think you probably want a `droplevels()` around that to get rid of the `""` *level*: `droplevels(X[-toBeRemoved, ])`

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `subset(X, genes != "")`

Comment: I'm quite certain it would. But I'm in my educational mode again, and see little reason not to use a named variable for clarity's sake.

Comment: @Roman Fairly certain it wouldn't, what with the bracket confusion ;-) `X <- X[-which(X$genes == ""), ]`

Comment: @Gavin IDEs and their syntax-checkers spoil a programmer, no doubt about it. :)

Answer (score 10):

@Nick Sabbe provided a great answer, but it has one caveat:

Using `-which(...)` is a neat trick to (sometimes) speed up the subsetting operation when there are only a few elements to remove.

...But if there are **no elements** to remove, it fails!

So, if `X$genes` **does not** contain any empty strings, `which` will return an empty integer vector. Negating that is still an empty vector. And X[integer(0)] returns an empty data.frame!

```
toBeRemoved <- which(X$genes=="")
if (length(toBeRemoved>0)) { # MUST check for 0-length
    X<-X[-toBeRemoved,]
}
```

Or, if the speed gain isn't important, simply:

```
X<-X[X$genes!="",]
```

Or, as @nullglob pointed out,

```
subset(X, genes != "")
```

Comment: Excellent caveat. Could also be `if ( length(toBeRemoved) ) {`. Further observation: using `subset` also removes all the rows where `is.na(X$genes)` is TRUE.